# setVisible does not work on List control in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have card and in which I have a list of which I have set the visibility false, and on click of card the below function I have written but the list does not appear or set to visible and I get an error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: this.setVisible is not a function

Please help me on this.

```
onClickCard: function (oEvent) {
    var _listCustom = this.getView().byId("listCustom");  
    this.setVisible(!_listCustom.getVisible());
    _listCustom.rerender(); 
}
```

Comment: Kindly share you complete code for better understanding

Comment: i have already added it..

Comment: You have added only the code which is trying to set the visibility. Not the complete card layout

Answer (score 0):

When you `setVisible` `false` to the list, you should `setVisible` `true` for the list only. In your case you were not setting it to the list.

```
onClickCard: function (oEvent) {
        var _listCustom = this.getView().byId("listCustom");  
        _listCustom.setVisible(!_listCustom.getVisible()); //setting visibility for list
        _listCustom.rerender(); 
    }
```

Comment: It does not give an error now but also does not set the list visible.

Comment: check what value is getting passed in !_listCustom.getVisible()

Comment: Add the xml view code as well, `this.getView().byId("listCustom").setVisible(true)` should work.

Comment: @shwetasrivastava First of all use model binding for your properties not the setters/getters.
Second rerender() is not needed here, two way binding as well as setVisible, is enough. What Card are using? sap.m.QuickViewCard? more infos pls

Comment: @Erch - i am using sap.f.card ; where do you mean i should use two way binding.

Comment: for model binding refer to https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.core.tutorial.databinding,

Comment: please add ur XML to the question, even though model binding is the proper way, your setters should work, the problem might be in how u built the XML